# Jquery on change situation

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
$('#sel_kat').change(function() {
    $("#" + this.value).show();
});
```

`#sel_kat` is set in CSS to `display: none;`. When I select some value inside a `<select>` tag, it show me a `div` with `id`. How can I hide this div when I select another value?

Comment: how come you use #sel_kat  as a <select> ..$('#sel_kat').change() and say #sel_kat is set in CSS to display: none;  you hava same ID  for div and select?

Answer (score 1):

First, put a common class on all the `div` elements related to the `select` values. Then you can hide them all before showing the selected one:

```
$('#sel_kat').change(function() {
    $('.sel_div').hide(); // hide all
    $("#" + this.value).show(); // show selected
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can hide the last item selected

```
$('#sel_kat').change(function() {
    var lastSelect = $('#sel_kat:last').val();
    $("#" + lastSelect).hide();
    $("#" + this.value).show(); // show selected
});
```